# Check all associations before destroy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an important model in my application, with many associations. If I want to check all the references in a before_destroy callback, i'd have to do something like:

```
has_many :models_1
has_many :models_2
mas_many :models_3
....
....
has_many :models_n

before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced

def :ensure_not_referenced
   if models_1.empty? and models_2.empty? and models_3.empty? and ... and models_n.empty?
       return true
   else
       return false
       errors.add(:base,'Error message')
   end
end
```

The question is, is there a way to perform all the validations at once?
Thanx!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass the `:dependent => :restrict` option to your `has_many` calls:

```
has_many :models, :dependent => :restrict
```

This way, you will only be able to destroy the object if no other associated objects reference it.

Other options are:

- **`:destroy`** - destroys every associated object calling their `destroy` method.
- **`:delete_all`** - deletes every associated object **without** calling their `destroy` method.
- **`:nullify`** - sets the foreign keys of the associated objects to `NULL` **without** calling their save callbacks.

Comment: I want to track those ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionErrors,and display it ..wot shoul;d I do?

Comment: its actually now:

:destroy
:delete
:nullify
:restrict_with_exception
:restrict_with_error

Answer (score 3):

Create a module into app/models/concerns/verification_associations.rb wiht:

```ruby
module VerificationAssociations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_destroy :check_associations
  end

  def check_associations
    errors.clear
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |association|
      if send(association.name).any?
        errors.add :base, :delete_association,
          model:            self.class.model_name.human.capitalize,
          association_name: self.class.human_attribute_name(association.name).downcase
      end
    end

    return false if errors.any?
  end

end
```

Create a new translation key into app/config/locales/rails.yml

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
     delete_association: Delete the %{model} is not allowed because there is an
                         association with %{association_name}
```

In your models include the module:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include VerificationAssociations
end
```