# Why does :dependent => :restrict throw an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

This question [Check all associations before destroy in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301054/check-all-associations-before-destroy-in-rails) suggests using `:dependent => :restrict`.

Why do I get `ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): dependent`?

Does this work with `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Why is there no mention in the docs? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Was it introduced after 3.0.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:dependent` cannot be used with `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  The docs you link to list the association methods that accept it: `has_many`, `has_one` and `belongs_to`.

You could add a `before_remove` hook and do your dependent check manually.